# Bootstrap Carousel is destroying CSS columns in Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, carousel

I have a Bootstrap Project which uses the TWBS Carousel and a 2-columned-list.

The Code is like:

```
<div id="header-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="1200">
    [Carousel stuff here ...]
</div>
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
                <h3>Cities in Germany</h3>
                <hr />
                <div class="multiCol">
                    <ul class="list-styled">
                        <li><a href="#">Berlin</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Hamburg</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Munich</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Cologne</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Kempten</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

You can find the full code here: http://jsfiddle.net/61sxephp/

I tested it in Firefox and Chrome. Firefox is showing it as expected and Chrome shows the list in 2 column while the Carousel is sliding and else in 1 column.

I can't get why...

Is there a possibility to use these components together in Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a bug almost similar to this: [**CSS Column layout blinks on dissapear on hover with transform and transition.**](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=460222)

The **temporary solution** in that thread is given as adding `transform: translatez(0)` to the child items.

```
.list-styled > li {
  position: relative;
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

[**Updated JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cauu8s39/1/)